# does case statement require a break command eventually

Tags: bash

Does a case statement always need a `break` statement eventually?  Otherwise it looks as if one ends up with an infinite loop.

Comment: A `case` does not loop, it handles conditions. You may be thinking of a `while` as those can be left to run for eternity, intentionally or otherwise.

Comment: Where does it look like you get an infinite loop?

Comment: I was looking at some code that does error parsing and the `break` was inside the case statement.  But then @matigo mentioned that the `break` is to exit the `while` loop, rather than the `case`.

Comment: No "break", but "return" may be useful to exit the case in the middle of the executed conditional block.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Break is used on loops. You may use case inside a loop, but case itself does not loop. You do need to close out the case block with an `esac`. For example:

```
#!/bin/bash

case "$1" in

a)
    echo $1
;;

b)
    echo $1
;;

*)
    echo $1
;;

esac
```